# How to make CachedRowSetImpl readonly

Tags: java, jdbc

I am going to execute a query and return result using **com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl** to the users (which are not in my control). I want to make sure that they will not perform **any** update operation on this object which can make changes in database.
One way could be:

1. Extend CachedRowSetImpl and override setReadOnly() method so that no user can set it to false.

Is this sufficient? Or there are any other ways using which users can still update database? Should I also override clone() method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason to override clone(), but the simplest way to make sure no updates can happen seems to be to use `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`.

As you see from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.html#updateInt%28int,%20int%29), all the mutators throw an SQLException in that case.

So to create a read-only cached row set, the following should suffice:

```
CachedRowSet rowSetImpl = new CachedRowSetImpl();
rowSetImpl.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rowSetImpl.setCommand("Select * from foo");
rowSetImpl.execute();
```

Comment: per [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#CONCUR_READ_ONLY) this field is Constant (static final int). Can not change it :)

Comment: I didn't mean to change the value of the constant you numbnuts. It's used in the query to define whether the ResultSet allows updates or not.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that. Also if you don't specify, result Set is "read only" by default [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)). Did't like your use of word "you numbnuts" despite me being it :) cause I didn't knew how to use this. Now, I am using both setReadOnly and CONCUR_READ_ONLY

Comment: For a CachedRowSetImpl the default concurrency is actually CONCUR_UPDATABLE, so the changes can propagate back to the database. That's why you need to modify it before you execute() the query.

Answer (score 1):

classes under `com.sun` are for internal use they provide reference implementation of APIs and you are not supposed to need access them directly.

It's better to avoid coupling your code to classes present in `com.sun`, and rather code against `javax.` or `java` packages

Moreover, classes in `com.sun`packages can be changed or dropped in any version of Java.

Comment: but the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) itself mentions-> _"Developers may use this implementation just as it is, **they may extend it**, or they may choose...."_

Comment: The `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl` is the reference implementation, so it is a slight deviation from that (it is even explicitly mentioned in the public api doc). But it would be better to use `RowSetProvider` and `RowSetFactory` to create an instance.